# Oracle DB to Big-query using Apache NiFi. Error while querying the same tables

Tags: oracle, google-bigquery, apache-nifi, dbmigrate

We are migrating all the tables from Oracle to Bigquery through Apache NiFi.  After successfully dumping the tables into Bigquery we are getting following Error while trying to query them in BQ CLI or GUI.

[image]

> Query Failed
>   Error: Not found: Dataset cloudcover-191610:mesdata. Please verify that the dataset exists and the correct location was used for the job.

Anyone has idea about this

Comment: I'm not sure this question is related to Oracle, is it?

Comment: show your query at least!

Comment: Could you describe how are you performing the operation or provide more context so we can help you, please?